# Unable to open serial port in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am trying to open COM1, but get a strange error every time I call `SerialPort.Open()`.

The error is:

> The given port name does not start with COM/com or does not resolve to a valid serial port.
>   Parameter name: portName

The code is very simple:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
port.Open();
```

If I call `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`, it returns one port called "COM1".

I've verified that I have a "COM1" on my computer, and I'm not using it in any other applications. When I run the code on another computer, it works. My system is running Windows Vista. The version of .NET is 2.0.

Is there a security setting I have to change somewhere? I'm logged in as an admin, and have UAC turned off.

---

**More info**

I used Process Explorer and confirmed that nothing is using \Device\Serial0.

---

**Workaround**

I installed a USB-Serial adaptor (COM3), and it works fine. Go figure. There must be a problem with COM1.

Comment: I know sometime the `GetPortNames()` gives wonky characters out of it.

Comment: Does hyperterminal work?

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too. It turned out that I had a printer set to use the COM port I was trying to open. Once I changed the printer to use another port the port opened just fine.

Comment: Thanks -- I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: How did you change it though?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, changing the printer's port can vary depending on which version of Windows you use. I suggest just "googling" the answer for your version of Windows.

Comment: Thanks, this was a solution for me, in the list of printers just right click in printer properties then in the Port tab check if the printer is using the com port you need, and just assign another port to the printer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting up the properties of the port, rather than using the constructor.

```
mPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
if(mPort.IsOpen)
{
   mPort.Close();
}
mPort.PortName = "COM1";
mPort.BaudRate = 19200;
mPort.Parity = Parity.None;
mPort.DataBits = 8;
mPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
mPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend; // Handshake.None;
mPort.Open();
```

I've also run into problems with Serial comm's and Microsoft Active Sync.  I'm not sure if you have this running or not, but it might be worth a shot to kill it (process name in the Task Manager is wcescomm.exe).  Hope that helps.

You could also try and use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() to see if something low level is causing a problem?  I'm not sure if that will give you more information.

Comment: You could (in this case) omit the call to .PortName, as this gets set to "COM1" internally by default.

Comment: And also DataBits and StopBits.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the notation \.\COMX instead of just COMX.
Ensure you escape the characters:
     "\\.\COM1"

Edit:Wops, SO escapes my \ so it should be like this (ommit spaces):
      "\ \ \ \ . \ \ COM1"

Comment: If I do that I get an exception stating the COM port cannot start with a \

Answer (score 1):

May be some application running in the background is probably opened your port(see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208094/force-a-com-port-to-close)).

Download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and use the "Find Handle or DLL" on the Find menu to find the process with the com port open. In my case spoolsv.exe always using COM1, COM3 port. so i used another com port (COM2) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the program I built in c# worked fine on my PC, but when  I ran it on other computers it won't initialize the serial port. I found out, the other pcs didn't have access to a database and that was affecting my program. Weird c# behavior.