# Is there a way to close or kill a 'hung' serial port using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

In Windows, sometimes the serial port "hangs" due to lost connection or some other reason beyond control of my app. When this happens we usually have to physically unplug the USB or shutdown the OS and restart.

Does anyone know if there is a way to send a Close or Kill command to an existing serial port that is opened by another app or service.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208094/force-a-com-port-to-close

Comment: thanks Elizion i'm in a similar dilemma

Comment: Have you tried the tools described in the linked answers?

Comment: andlabs, thanks for replying. Not as yet, it is usually something that happens on the customer computer so I don't have the luxury of diagnosing the problem there. These tools would help me diagnose if it is an issue with our device. From the answers, it seems it is not possible to "kill" an existing COM connection.